# How to read data when sent by DELETE method?

Tags: javascript, php, fetch, http-delete

I am firt time trying DELETE method with fetch in javascript. I just want to read the sent data from my fetch in php. I am doing this:

```
... in js
fetch(this.url+"?deleteID="+ID,{method:'DELETE'})  

... in php
 if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'DELETE')){
     $id=  $_GET["deleteID"];
}
```

but it is failing and I do not know why. The definition of `$_GET` is "An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters" and I am passing `deleteID` as a param or not ? (When the method is GET, this works)
Thanks for explanation.

Comment: According to the documentation, [`$_GET`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) will work with "...all requests with a query string" which would include DELETE. So look closely at the URL, perhaps it's not correctly formed?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, for help. Yes, I was using wrong URL...

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry, this works... I was using wrong URL